# JavaScript/HTML5 Canvas Pathfinding Multiplexing Issue

Tags: javascript, html, artificial-intelligence, path-finding

I have a pathfinding script in JavaScript for HTML5 canvas that appears to have an issue with multiplexing.

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Eb2CH/)

The script has been taken and slightly adapted from the accepted SO answer here: [A* Start path finding in HTML5 Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11331834/a-start-path-finding-in-html5-canvas) (which also has the same bug).

**How to replicate the issue:** Simply click quickly around the map while the red square is in motion, and you will see what appears to be the square splitting or branching off into each of the different paths.

I think what is happening is, as you should notice that the red squares start flickering during branching, it's actually just the same square trying to be in multiple places at the same time, causing the same square to "teleport" back and forth with the frame rate in alternating frames. This is just a theory though, but I don't think it's actually spawning more squares.

I'm not sure if it has to do with the `movePlayer()` function or the `pathFinding()` function. I think what I need to do is, if the object is moving and the target tile is updated, cancel any previous operation(s) instead of continuing to run them simultaneously - I have no idea how I would do this though.

As this will eventually be an enemy AI script, the target tile will always be updating in real-time as the player moves around the map, which will likely cause this issue to surface.

Thanks, and I appreciate any help in debugging this!

Comment: i would try to precalculate frames and smooth it

Comment: @philipp You mean some sort of frame buffering?

Comment: at least for the view/rendering-part

Comment: @philipp I'll check into ways of doing that and give it a shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, the problem is with the timers being used. When you click, it's calculating the path between the current location and where you click, then it starts a timer that causes the square to move along that path, storing the information locally for that timer. When you click again, it starts another timer without clearing the old one, so it is now moving along two paths simultaneously from two different timers. It's drawing out every movement in each timer, and this can be seen as the flickering.

Comment: So you're saying that because `movePlayer()` is calling itself recursively, that's being compounded every time the target time is updated if `movePlayer()` is currently already running? What do you propose for a solution?

Comment: There are two easy solutions that I can think of. The first, possibly easiest, is to clear the old timer when a new one starts. When calling setTimeout, set the result to a global variable (setTimeout/setInterval return an integer timer ID for reference). Before calling setTimeout, call clearTimeout on the stored ID number, which will stop the previous timer from completing. The second is to store the path globally instead of locally, but then you would still probably need to manage timers.

Comment: It didn't work :(. `var timer     = (function(data, step) { window.setTimeout(function() { movePlayer(data, step) }, 60) });`, `canvas.onclick = function(e) { [...] clearTimeout(timer); }`, `function movePlayer(data, step) { [...] timer(data, step); }`. Same issue as before.

Comment: I should have just given you a solved version. As you can probably tell by my reputation, I'm kind of new to the StackExchange format. http://jsfiddle.net/9tBYj/ The only differences are the addition of the timerID global variable and an extra clearTimeout before setTimeout.

Comment: Actually, it DID work! I reread your previous comment and this time set it to a global var (rather than a function inside the global var), then set it to `window.setTimeout()` inside of the `movePlayer()` function. Now it works! Thanks!